# Who's calling my interrupt handler if I have both CIAs turned off?

Tags: interrupt, timing, c64

I'm trying to set up a simple raster interrupt handler to change the background color in a given stripe. However, my interrupt handler seems to be called all the time. (the code uses CA65's format)

```
.include "c64.inc"

ROW = 100

.segment "ZPSAVE"

.segment "STARTUP"

        sei

        ;; Turn off BASIC and KERNAL ROM
        lda #$35
        sta $01

        ;; Flush CIA IRQs
        bit CIA1_ICR
        bit CIA2_ICR

        ;; Turn off CIA interrupts
        lda #%011111111
        sta CIA1_ICR
        sta CIA2_ICR

        ;; Set target raster line
        lda #%01111111
        and VIC_CTRL1
        sta VIC_CTRL1

        lda #ROW
        sta VIC_HLINE

        ;; Enable VIC interrupt
        lda #%00000001
        sta VIC_IMR

        ;; Install interrupt handler
        lda #<isr
        sta $fffe
        lda #>isr
        sta $ffff
        cli

        rts

.macro isr_pre
        pha
        txa
        pha
        tya
        pha
.endmacro

.macro isr_post
        pla
        tay
        pla
        tax
        rti
.endmacro

;;; Acknowledge VIC interrupt
.macro ack_vic
        lda VIC_IRR
        and #$01
        sta VIC_IRR
.endmacro

.proc isr
        isr_pre
        ack_vic

        ;; Uncommenting these lines works around the problem
        ;; lda VIC_HLINE
        ;; cmp #ROW
        ;; bne exit

        lda #1
        sta VIC_BORDERCOLOR
        sta VIC_BG_COLOR0

        ldx #50
:       dex
        bne :-

        lda #0
        sta VIC_BORDERCOLOR
        sta VIC_BG_COLOR0

exit:   isr_post
.endproc
```

If I comment out the three lines marked as the "workaround" in the above code, then my interrupt handler is called all the time, not just on (the start of) row `ROW`:

[image: Without workaround]

If I uncomment those three lines, then it works, but it's very unstable, I guess because of those same unintended interrupts:

[image: With workaround]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found several problems with my code as posted above, and fixing all of them fixed the problem:

1. The bitmask for turning off `CIA` interrupts was wrong (it was accidentally 9 bits long) -- this is what was causing all those extra interrupt firings...
2. The `ISR` postscriptum macro was missing a `pla` to restore the `A` register -- this screwed up state royally, so whatever happened with the old code was more-or-less by chance...
3. The `VIC` interrupt was not flushed in the interrupt setup code -- so after fixing the previous two problems, now the interrupts were never triggered.
4. There's nothing to `rts` to at the end of the setup code, since we turn off kernal and BASIC ROM

So the fixed code is as follows:

```
.include "c64.inc"

ROW = 100

;;; Acknowledge VIC interrupt
.macro ack_vic
        lda VIC_IRR
        and #$01
        sta VIC_IRR
.endmacro

.segment "ZPSAVE"

.segment "STARTUP"

        sei

        ;; Turn off BASIC and KERNAL ROM
        lda #$35
        sta $01

        ;; Flush CIA IRQs
        bit CIA1_ICR
        bit CIA2_ICR
        ack_vic

        ;; Turn off CIA interrupts
        lda #%01111111
        sta CIA1_ICR
        sta CIA2_ICR

        ;; Set target raster line
        lda #%01111111
        and VIC_CTRL1
        sta VIC_CTRL1

        lda #ROW
        sta VIC_HLINE

        ;; Enable VIC interrupt
        lda #%00000001
        sta VIC_IMR

        ;; Install interrupt handler
        lda #<isr
        sta $fffe
        lda #>isr
        sta $ffff
        cli    
        jmp *

.macro isr_pre
        pha
        txa
        pha
        tya
        pha
.endmacro

.macro isr_post
        pla
        tay
        pla
        tax
        pla
        rti
.endmacro

.proc isr
        isr_pre
        ack_vic

        lda #1
        sta VIC_BORDERCOLOR
        sta VIC_BG_COLOR0

        ldx #50
:       dex
        bne :-

        lda #0
        sta VIC_BORDERCOLOR
        sta VIC_BG_COLOR0

exit:   isr_post
.endproc
```

This results, as expected, in a solid white stripe. For some unknown reason, the stripe starts at the middle of the screen horizontally, but I guess that'd be one for a separate SO question.